# Uinviersal property of basis of a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let V be a vector space over a field k. Let B be a subset of V. If any set map from B to any vector space W can be extended uniquely to a k-linear map from V to W.  Then B is a basis of V.

Can someone help with the proof.

Comment: This should be edited to be:  If any set map from B to any vector space W can be extended "UNIQUELY" to V then ...

Comment: U r right. Thanx.

Comment: Extended to a *linear* function $V\longrightarrow W$, I understand.

Answer (score 1):

Take $W=k^{|B|}$ and the bijection $b_i\in B\mapsto (0,\cdots,1,\cdots,0)\in k^{|B|}$ (a one in the $i$-th position). Extend this map.

Comment: How do you write the tuple if cardinality of B is infinite ?

Comment: I was thinking in the finite dimensional case. The generalization is the function $s:B\longrightarrow k$ $s(b)=1$ for $b=b_i$ and $s(b)=0$ for $b\ne b_i$. But I'm not sure if the result is true in infinite dimension.

Comment: Thanx. Got it. Your $k^{|B|}$ is nothing but span of B right?

Comment: Almost right. The span of the *image* of $B$.

Comment: But Martin the map from B to $k^{|B|}$ is not a bijection . It is just an injective map. There are other elements like $(1,1,.....)$. Isn't it?

Comment: The span of $\text{Im}(B)$ isn't the full cartesian product, but the subset of functions with only a finite number of $s(b)\ne 0$.

Comment: For simplicity let us consider the cardinality of the set B finite , let us assume it to be 3. Call the elements $b_1,b_2,b_3$. SO we send $b_1,b_2,b_3$ to $(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)$ resp. But then $k^{|B|}$ has elements like $(1,1,1)$, which doesn't have a pre-image. So how is the map surjective? Am I doing some stupid mistake?

Comment: $f(b_1+b_2+b_3)=\cdots$

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13888/discussion-between-susobhan-and-martin-blas-perez-pinilla)